# Access variables in other file in node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to define a variable in one file called vars.js. then I want to access those variable from another file called mybot.js. this is what I ahve in each file:

vars.js:
`var token = 'abcfgk6'`

mybot.js:

```
var request = require(./vars.js);
...
bot.login(token);
```

Comment: Please always search before posting a question. This has been answered already many many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export your variable in `vars.js`. See also [this StackOverflow thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it) for detailed explanations. Your code could look e.g. like this:

```
// vars.js
exports.token = 'abcfgk6';
// mybot.js
var request = require('./vars.js');
bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to export the variable in `vars.js`

```
var token = 'abcfgk6'
exports.token = token;
```

And then access via:

```
var request = require(./vars.js);
...
bot.login(request.token);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use json in your external files. It makes it allot easier to manage large amounts of data.

vars.js:

```
module.exports = {
    'token': 'abcfgk6'
};
```

Then access it with:

```
var request = require(./vars.js);

request.token;
```