# Cannot import javascript file in Gulpfile

Tags: javascript, gulp

I try to use function from another Javascript file in my Gulpfile, but cannot make it work so far.

The file I need to access in Gulpfile:

```
var hello = function(){
   console.log('Hello')
}
```

And the way I require it in my Gulpfile:

```
var tools = require('./public/js/tools.js'); 
gulp.task('create_subscriptions', function(){
    tools.hello();
});
```

`tools.hello() is not a function` is triggered.

What do I do wrong here?

**Edit**

I did

```
module.exports = {
    hello: hello()
};
```

Whats the difference wit `exports.hello = hello`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Comment: You should remove `()` unless you return a new function.. So, `hello: hello`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't export anything from your module. Local variables are not exposed, you need to explicitly mark them as public.

```
exports.hello = hello;
```

---

```
hello: hello()
```

You have `()` after the variable holding the function. You are **calling** it and assigning the **return value** (which is not a function) to your hello property.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Can you check my edit and may be explain me?