# How to avoid using module in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apnagent

Doing this [tutorial](https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/developing-ios-push-notifications-nodejs), and I do not want to use `device.js` just to put one line in it: `module.exports = "<a1 ..`

[image]

How could put this device ID in my main script, and pass it to `apnagent` object? Tried this, but I guess this is why connection not establishing.

Maybe instead of `module.exports = "<388 ..` I need something like `agent.set('something', and here the device ID);` ?

```
var pfx = '/var/lib/openshift/555dd1415973ca1660000085/app-root/runtime/repo/pfx.p12';
module.exports = "<38873D3B 0D61A965 C1323D6C 0A9F2866 D1BB50A3 64F199E5 483862A6 7F02049C>"; // <----- THIS HERE

var apnagent = require('apnagent')
var agent = module.exports = new apnagent.Agent();
agent.set('pfx file', pfx);
// our credentials were for development
agent.enable('sandbox');

console.log('LOG1');
console.log(agent);
agent.connect(function (err) {

console.log('LOG2');
  // gracefully handle auth problems
  if (err && err.name === 'GatewayAuthorizationError') {
    console.log('Authentication Error: %s', err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  // handle any other err (not likely)
  else if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  // it worked!
  var env = agent.enabled('sandbox')
    ? 'sandbox'
    : 'production';

  console.log('apnagent [%s] gateway connected', env);
});
```

Comment: Maybe helpful: [What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var pfx = '/var/lib/openshift/555dd1415973ca1660000085/app-root/runtime/repo/pfx.p12';
var deviceId = "<38873D3B 0D61A965 C1323D6C 0A9F2866 D1BB50A3 64F199E5 483862A6 7F02049C>"; // <----- THIS HERE

var apnagent = require('apnagent')
var agent = new apnagent.Agent(deviceId);
agent.set('pfx file', pfx);
// our credentials were for development
agent.enable('sandbox');

console.log('LOG1');
console.log(agent);
agent.connect(function (err) {

console.log('LOG2');
  // gracefully handle auth problems
  if (err && err.name === 'GatewayAuthorizationError') {
    console.log('Authentication Error: %s', err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  // handle any other err (not likely)
  else if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  // it worked!
  var env = agent.enabled('sandbox')
    ? 'sandbox'
    : 'production';

  console.log('apnagent [%s] gateway connected', env);
});
```

The explanation is this: module.exports is the common module export syntax. This way you are avoiding exporting a module and importing it by manually hardcoding the deviceId in your code.

Comment: Should I use `deviceId =` or `device =` because the script originally called `device.js`?!

Comment: It is the name of a variable; you can use the name you want.