# module.exports.report.logon is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, cognos

I'm trying to get the login to work on a scheduler, but getting the `module.exports.report.logon is not a function` error. This is the code:

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
const cms = require("g4js-cognos").Cms;
module.exports.report = new cms(url, namespace, usr, psw);

let task = cron.schedule('*/1 * * * *', function() {
    logonToCognos();
}, true);

task.start();

function logonToCognos() {
    module.exports.report.logon().then((response) => {  // THE ERROR
        console.log(" LOGGED on, status: " + response.statusCode);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(" Logon on fail: " + error);
    });
}
```

When I'm not using scheduller and `module.exports.report` is outside of a function, everything works fine:

```
const cms = require("g4js-cognos").Cms;
module.exports.report = new cms(url, namespace, usr, psw);

module.exports.report.logon().then((response) => {
    console.log(" LOGGED on, status: " + response.statusCode);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(" Logon on fail: " + error);
});
```

Also, if I don't use module.exports, it is working fine (but I have to use exports because I need it in another module):

```
const cms = require("g4js-cognos").Cms;
const report = new cms(url, namespace, usr, psw);

let task = cron.schedule('*/1 * * * *', function() {
    logonToCognos();
}, true);

task.start();

function logonToCognos() {
    report.logon().then((response) => {  // NO ERROR
        console.log(" LOGGED on, status: " + response.statusCode);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(" Logon on fail: " + error);
    });
}
```

Any ideas? Why is module.exports working so different? Thanks.

Comment: Probably has something to do with scope.  You're inside the scope of function logonToCognos so module might not be defined.  Have you tried passing the constructed cms as a parameter of the function?

Comment: If, instead of module.exports.report, I put const report, then it is working fine. Why is module.export behaving so different?

Comment: I edited the question to have that example as well.

Comment: Are you somehow mutating/re-assigning the exported `report` object in some script that is `require()`ing this module?

Comment: I don't think so. The only place I use it is in 1 other file, where I have: const appJs = require("../app"); module.exports.readAll = (req) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
        appJs.report.getExportById(reportId, params, 'XML')
            .then((data) => {
                resolve(data);
            }).catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });        
    })
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
const cms = require("g4js-cognos").Cms;

// init your class
const report = new cms(url, namespace, usr, psw);

// define what to do after logon
report.logon().then((response) => { 
  console.log(" LOGGED on, status: " + response.statusCode);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(" Logon on fail: " + error);
});

// define cron job
const task = cron.schedule('*/1 * * * *', function() {
  report.logon();
}, true);

// start cron job
task.start();

// finally export your class
module.exports.report = report;
```

maybe this can help you [module.exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

try injecting `module.exports.report`:

```
    const cron = require('node-cron');
    const cms = require("g4js-cognos").Cms;
    module.exports.report = new cms(url, namespace, usr, psw);

    let task = cron.schedule('*/1 * * * *', function() {
        logonToCognos(module.exports.report);
    }, true);

    task.start();

    function logonToCognos(report) {
        report.logon().then((response) => {  // THE ERROR
            console.log(" LOGGED on, status: " + response.statusCode);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(" Logon on fail: " + error);
        });
  }
```

Comment: Got "report.logon is not a function"