# NodeJs - [Restful API] How to separate app get methods in different js files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api

I am new to Node.js.
Currently I am helping my team to develop a restful api with Nodejs.
I would like to ask if I have to implement all the app.get methods and business logics in single file?

For example, my server.js:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()
let family = {}

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.route('/family')
  .get(function (request, response) {
    response.json(family)
  })
  .post(function (request, response) {
    family[request.body.isbn] = {
      name: request.body.name,
      relationship: request.body.relationship,
      age: request.body.age
    }

    response.json({message: 'Success'})
  })

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Server is started')
});
```

How if I wanna build a file call family.js and move all family related logic inside from server.js?

And how to call it from server.js?

Anybody can help? thanks.

Comment: No you don't have to. You can define all family logic as functions in other file and export those functions. Read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Off course you can. The main thing is, how do you pass `app` reference to your modules. I've created modules and passed `app` instance in the main function of the module.

**Folder Structure:**

```
server.js
    /routes
        family.js
        login.js
        user.js
        ...
```

---

**server.js**

```
//include
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json())

//init routes
require('../routes/family')(app); //passing "app" instance
require('../routes/login')(app);
require('../routes/user')(app);

//start server
app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Server is started')
});
```

**family.js**

```
//routes
module.exports = function(app) {  //receiving "app" instance
    app.route('/family')
        .get(getAPI)
        .post(postAPI);
}

//API functions
function getAPI(request, response) {
    response.json(family);
}

function postAPI(request, response) {
    family[request.body.isbn] = {
        name: request.body.name,
        relationship: request.body.relationship,
        age: request.body.age
    }

    response.json({message: 'Success'});
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
It works for me after removing "route('/family')" in family.js. (It alerts app.route is not a function, why?)

Comment: and why did you remove `app.route('/family')` from `family.js`? It creates the route..

Comment: Error alerts "app.route is not a function". I modified the code to 
"app.get(getAPI); app.post(postAPI);" and it can run...

Comment: @TechHolic Express works with both syntax, I am not sure why the other one is throwing error as I haven't used it for a while..