# node.js class SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js

I write my class like that on node

```
class hello {
 function helloworld(){

       console.log('helloworld');


   }



};
```

but when I run my server i get this error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>
> function helloworld(id){
>            ^^^^^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Remove `;`, what happend after removing the semicolon?

Comment: @C0dekid still have the same error

Comment: Remove function word..all should work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defining method in JS classes you don't need to use function keyword. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

You can simply just do.

```
class hello {
     helloworld () {
        console.log('helloworld');
     }
}

var a = new hello();
a.helloworld();
//to export from file
exports.hello = hello;
```

Then in other file.

```
var myClass = require('yourModule');
var a = new myClass.hello();
a.helloworld();
```

Read this:
[What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but how i export this methods to other file ?