# Serve HTML with Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have an HTML file (privacy.html) and I want to serve it as home. I wrote the following:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
  res.write(require('./privacy.html'))
  res.end()
})
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/privacy.html');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't use `require` to include html. Take a look at express's [`res.sendFile`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) and [`express.static`](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). It looks like you probably want the latter, but the former is the more flexible one if you're sure you want the structure you have.

Here's [a little more information about `require` and the module system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it/5311377#5311377).

Edit: I urge you to read the links I provided, but I'll give you some code to use anyway so you don't end up using bad techniques.

The full implementation is super-simple:

```
// Somewhere above, probably where you `require()` express and friends.
const path = require('path')

// Later on. app could also be router, etc., if you ever get that far

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'privacy.html'))
})

// If you think it's still readable, you should be able rewrite this as follows.

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'privacy.html')))
```

There are ways to make this fancier (bindings, etc.), but none of them are worth doing when this works fine as-is. This will work everywhere that `express` does, including on systems where the path delimiter/file system hierarchy is different.

Comment: Itried with `res.write(express.static('./privacy.html'))` bot it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: yeah but I don't have a directory, it's just a file and I don't wanna create a new directory for one file. I also tried `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'privacy.html'))`

Answer (score 1):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + 'privacy.html');
});
```

Here is a good example: https://codeforgeek.com/render-html-file-expressjs/

Comment: Link is broken.