# How to use module.exports of Nodejs

Tags: node.js

How do we export two or more functions out of a .js file using module.exports in Node.js and require() at the other .js file. In that case, how do we access the functions imported by require() ?

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it

Comment: Thanks , it cleared my doubt.

Comment: I fount a simple example : https://wiki.workassis.com/node-js-export-and-import/