# JS - How to access a module.exports function in the same file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that looks like:

```
module.exports = myFunction() {
  //do some stuff
}
```

I can access it fine from other file using `var myFunction = require(.thepath.js)`

However how can i access it from the file that it was created.

I've tried `myFunction()` and `this.myFunction()` but neither work.

Thanks

Comment: what about `myFunction.myFunction()` ??

Comment: var fn = function() {}; module.exports = fn;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save it to a variable then export the variable like so:

```
// Create the function
const myFunction = function() {

}

// Call the function
myFunction();

// Export the function
module.exports = myFunction
```

Comment: better use const over let

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón - the answer is looking good but for my undertasnidng why `const` over `let`?

Comment: `const` means that the variable will never change whereas `let` means it could change.

Comment: because this is a invariable method, and make it no chaged over others

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn thanks - so that function returns some variables I presume when you say 'nothing will change' that doesnt apply to the response return provides. of course I tested this and it didnt but good to confirm :)

Comment: @userMod2 when using a const the value root itself won't change (string, integer, array, function, etc.). However.... in objects when using a const, you can change the child objects values.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Awesome - thanks once again! Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could actually use an anonyomous function here if you didn't want to call it in the same file

```
module.exports = function (){
    // do some stuff
}
```

<s>As long as you give it a name, you can just call it by using its name.</s>

<s>module.exports = function myFunction(){</s>

<s>// do some stuff</s>


}

myFunction()

Sorry, I remembered this incorrectly. There is a scoping problem here that can be solved by defining the function seperately from the assignment.

```
function myFunction (){
    // do some stuff
}
module.exports = myFunction

myFunction()
```

Comment: I need to use it in the same file

Comment: I updated this response, I made a clear mistake in my original answer.

Comment: Also, here's a fun variant that you shouldn't actually use because it will bewilder anyone else trying to reading your code. Once you've assigned a function to `module.exports`, just call `module.exports();` to run it. =P

Answer (score 1):

```
var func = module.exports = myFunction(){
   //do some stuff here
}
```

Now you can access through variable.