# Node.js access to a method from another module

Tags: node.js, module

I would to access to a method from another module calling that method inside a route.
with this notation of module.exports does't work beacause in my console I get an error like getProducts is not a function

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');
const productsController = require('../controller/productsController')

const productModel = require('../models/productModel');

// send html file
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/esercitazione-AJAX.html'));
  });
  //to  /getProducts call a method from productsController
  router.get('/getProducts', function (req, res){

  productsController.productsController()
});

module.exports = router;
```

this is my module

```
//productsController.js
const productModel = require('../models/productModel');

var productsController = function() {
  console.log('productsController')

  var getProducts = function(req,res,callback) {
    var callback = function(result) {

      res.send(result);
    }
    productModel.getProducts(req, res, callback);
  }
}

module.exports = new  productsController();
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you export not a function, but an object. Just export a function:

```
module.exports = productsController;
```

Another problem, is that your function has incorrect name, `productsController` is a module, but function name should be something like `getProducts`:

```
exports.getProducts = function() {
  console.log('getProducts ')

  var getProducts = function(req,res,callback) {
    ...
```

And use it so:

```
const productsController = require('../controller/productsController');

productsController.getProducts();
```

Comment: if I use this notation  I get this error                                                 
TypeError: productsController.getProducts is not a function, I need to export an object and access to a method productsController, this is my goal

Comment: my mistake sorry,  Now I've copied the right code, but this kind of exports is equals to module.exports = new module();

Comment: What do you mean? `exports.getProducts` adds a new field to a module object.

Comment: I used exports.getProducts, with this notation I ' am exporting all module or just the method getProducts?,

Comment: You don't understand the conception of CommonJs module, read this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it) to understand it.