# Exporting functions

Tags: javascript

I have a question, I am a new JavaScript developer, I'm not sure why my modules are not exporting. This is what I tried.

```
var add = function(a, b) {
    return a+b
}
module.exports = {
    add: add
}
```

Comment: What you have tried to say that is it not exporting ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Comment: @RandyCasburn What makes you assume this has to do with Node.js?

Comment: This doesn't give us nearly enough information to help you out