# React component, npm install throws error while npm link works

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-link

I've created a small react component, and uploaded it to a private npm.
I try to implement it in my create-react app.
When I use it localy (npm link), all works preferct
But when I try to use to server version (npm install), I get the following error

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to export the module. Please check the purpose of export.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to export your component somewhere i.e.

```
import React from 'react';
class Comp1 extends React.Component {
 //code here
}

export default Comp1;
```

Comment: I did export it using default.
And if I look at the non minimized build file, I can see "exports.default = MyComp"