# Passing variable by Using NodeJS express module

Tags: html, node.js

I am using the express module to do some simple variable passing.

The below are my codes

```
    app.get('/dosomething', function(req, res){ 
          var myText = req.query.mytext; //mytext is the name of your input box
          console.log(myText);

          var googleSent = require("./dosomethingelse");
     });
```

Basically, I have an html form which will send some text to NodeJS on submit.
It successfully goes into the NodeJs and I am able to console it out. But I am not able to use the variable within the **dosomethingelse.js**, I tried to use `module.export` but I realize this doesn't really fit my case.

So are there s a solution for this or I am not doing it in the right way?

Let's ask this question in another way:

> ```
>     app.get('/dosomething', function(req, res){ 
>         var myText = req.query.mytext; //mytext is the name of your input box
>         console.log(myText);
>
>         module.exports.myText = myText;
>      });
>
>
>     app.get('/dosomething2', function(req, res){ 
>             console.log(app.mytext)
>          });
> ```

Let's say I got my result in the first `app.get` and I want the **dosomething2** able to console the same result, I tried the code above but it seems it does not work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Comment: Can you post your dosomethingelse.js file code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define global variable and use it in any file

```
app.get('/dosomething', function(req, res){ 

          global.myText = req.query.mytext;
          console.log(myText);
          var googleSent = require("./dosomethingelse");
});
```

in your dosomethingelse file :

```
module.exports=function(){
     console.log('from file',global.myText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a common container. You can use create a container and pass it to `dosomethingelse` or use a singleton

```
// singleton.js
class Singleton {

  set myText(value) {
    this._myText = value;
  }

  get myText() {
    return this._myText;
  }
}
module.exports = new Singleton();
```

In your app

```
// app.js
const singleton = require('./singleton');
app.get('/dosomething', function(req, res) {
   singleton.myText = req.query.myText;
   // ....
 });
// dosomethingelese.js
const singleton = require('./singleton');
console.log(singleton.myText);
```