# Using exports in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and trying to use some generated code and running into some issues regarding exports. As file1 is auto-generated, if possible I would prefer to edit file2 only.

In file1.js I have:

```
var exports = function(apiClient) {
    ...
    this.apiClient = apiClient || ApiClient.instance;
    this.listAssets = function(opts, callback) {
    ...
    }
}
```

I want to use the function `listAssets` in file2.js. I tried doing the following in file2.js:

```
var myInstance = require('../../jsCode/src/api/file1');
```

and then calling `myInstance.getAssets()`, but that is clearly incorrect. I assume that I am missing something pretty obvious, but after looking around I still couldn't figure it out. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/5311377/7362396 - basically it says you may use just `exports`, but must not re-assign it like you do with `var`. Or just use the full `module.exports`.

Comment: Read through this, so if I want to keep the var exports part (Would prefer to not change autogenerated code) where can I use the module.exports?

Comment: Then you can do `module.exports = exports` at the end of `file1.js`

Answer (score 1):

Use `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = function(apiClient) {
    ...
    this.apiClient = apiClient || ApiClient.instance;
    this.listAssets = function(opts, callback) {
    ...
    }

    // now return an object containing the API you need in your import
    return { 
        apiClient: this.apiClient, 
        listAssets: this.listAssets 
    };
}
```

and then require the module as you suggested:

```
var myInstance = require('../../jsCode/src/api/file1')(apiClient);
```

This is called **CommonJS** and is a set of agreements of how to handle module exports and imports. Remember your imported function needs to be passed `apiClient` as an argument.

Comment: Interesting - I assume that my problem is the passing apiClient. What does the (apiClient) after the require statement do?

Comment: It executes the imported function with `apiClient` as an argument.

Comment: And if file1 already requires apiClient and uses it, in file2 when I am importing file1, do I need to instantiate a new apiClient instance, or will that be taken care of by file1?

Comment: The way you access apiClient seems a little unusual. Can't you just require the apiClient in file1? Since your module in file1 exports its apiClient, you can use that in fileX where you import from file1.

Comment: Earlier in file1 is the line `module.exports = factory(require('../ApiClient')`

Comment: You can only have one generic module.exports per file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178712/discussion-between-a-k-and-connexo).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following solution:

```
module.exports = function()
```

Comment: Where would I use this? In file2?

Comment: module.exports = function(apiClient) {
    ...
    this.apiClient = apiClient || ApiClient.instance;
    this.listAssets = function(opts, callback) {
    ...
    }
}

Comment: that change isnt ideal as I would prefer to not change file1 (its autogenerated code), but even with this fix I still cant call the methods defined in this function. Any way to do this by changing my procedure in file2?