# Importing string values to pass to an API call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twilio

I have a ([Twilio](https://twilio.com/)) API call which requires credentials **`accountSid`** and **`authToken`**.

---

**`twilio.js`**

```
const twilio = require('twilio');
const accountSid = require('./auth/twilio_credentials');
const authToken = require('./auth/twilio_credentials');

console.log('accountSid: ' + accountSid);
console.log('authToken: ' + authToken);

module.exports = new twilio.Twilio(accountSid, authToken);
```

---

For security, instead of pasting the values directly into code, I have them in separate file. The credentials are used in the file at the same level as the **`auth`** folder

**`auth/twilio_credentials.js`**

```
module.exports = accountSid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
module.exports = authToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

---

From the console logs (and using **`typeof`**), I was able to verify that the strings are being imported properly to that point, but when I run the code, I get **`throw new Error('accountSid is required');`**. However, it works when I paste the values directly into the file.

I feel like this is a wonky JavaScript thing that I'm missing. What's the difference between importing the string value from a different file, versus directly using a hard-coded value?

Comment: Have you tried using a .env? And then bringing it in that way? Seems like it should work

Comment: Try formatting it like this. module.exports.creds={accountSid:’’,authToken:’’} then require().creds.accountSid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try exporting them like this:

```
exports.accountSid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
exports.authToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

And then, import them like this:

```
const {accountSid, authToken} = require("./auth/twilio_credentials");
```

I will suggest you to check how module.exports and exports work in Node.js here:
[What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Comment: Thank you for the code and the doc! I see my blatant typo now smh.