# Problem using function in exported custom module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to nodejs and I am trying to export my custom module but it says function is not defined or is not a function.

I have created a module which contains a function to validate the request body using Joi library. Below is what I have done

**validator.js**

```
const Joi = require('joi');

var validateCustomer = function(customer) {
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string().min(3).required()
    }

    return Joi.validate(customer, schema)
}

module.exports.validator = validateCustomer;
```

**customers.js**

```
const validator = require('../myModules/validator');

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const {error} = validator(req.body);
    if(error) return res.error(404).send(error.details[0].message);
    ...some code 
});
```

Please help

Answer (score 3):

Change out

```
module.exports.validator = validateCustomer;
```

for

```
module.exports = validateCustomer
```

in `validator.js`.

Comment: Thanks.. it works.. but can you explain why i cannot use module.exports.validator = validateCustomer ?

Comment: Well let's think about what that's trying to say. `module.exports.validateCustomer` is looking for the `module` object's `exports` property's `validateCustomer` property. I don't believe that exists in any fashion. As such, you're setting a value that doesn't exist. I reccomend reading up on `module.exports()`, there's a relatively large number of well written guides, all easy to find.

Comment: Please check my updated comment. I try to set validator = validateCustomer which is my function

Comment: by the same reason, you're setting `module.exports.validator`, which is not a field or property that exists.

Comment: You're just trying to declare to the larger JS enviroment "this module has a function called this and you're allowed to use it!" There's no need to associate it with anything.

Comment: As well, `module` in this case represents the "idea" of `validator.js`, which has some exports, specifically the `validateCustomer` function. It doesn't make sense to say `validator.exports.validator = foo()`

Comment: I can see something similar explained in this question's accepted answer so i didn't get it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it

Comment: Can you please explain what does that mean in the above question URL? Because i didn't understand it and it is similar to something what I was doing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need help with. The question you linked gives a more clear explanation that I could have provided.