# Cant get what i want from module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im trying to export prefix from my "prefix.js" to "index.js" and I want it to return "?" becuse the prefix on the database is "?"

This is my code for "prefix.js"

```
const GuildConfig = require("../database/schemas/GuildConfig");
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client();

const prefix = () => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  const guildConfig = GuildConfig.findOne({
    guildId: message.guild.id,
  });
  const prefix = guildConfig.get("prefix");Z
  return prefix
};

exports.prefix = prefix
```

And this is some of the code from "index.js"

```
const prefix = require("./src/events/prefix")

console.log(prefix)
```

And this is what I get in the console

{ prefix: [Function: prefix] }

Comment: It's because the `prefix` export isn't the _default export_, so you'll have to either access it through [_object destructuring_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) or by `prefix.prefix`. Alternatively, you should instead use `module.exports` - more info about it can be found in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5311334).

Answer (score 0):

You can tie prefix to export when you declare the function earlier or export it later by using {} braces.

1. export function prefix() {}

OR

2. prefix = () => {}

export {prefix}

Here's an article that clears up export/import a bit:
https://javascript.info/import-export

Comment: The OP's using the Node.JS module system, not ES6 modules.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

What you have to do is call your **prefix** function as the following:

#### Option 1 (By deconstructing your object)

```
const { prefix } = require("./src/events/prefix")
console.log(prefix())
```

#### Option 2 (By calling your function)

```
const prefix = require("./src/events/prefix")
console.log(prefix.prefix())
```

### Reference

[NodeJS exports](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports)