# What does require() return which is used in app.use()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In **./app_api/routes/index.js**

```
var router = express.Router()
var ctrlLocations = require('../controllers/locations')
router.post( '/', ctrlLocations.helloCreate );
module.exports = router
```

In **app.js**

```
var routesApi = require('./app_api/routes/index');
app.use('/', routesApi)
```

I am guessing that variable `routesApi` contains a reference to the variable `router` of `index.js`.
What does `require()` return which is used in `app.use()`?

How does `app.use('/', routesApi)` know which function to call from `index.js`. There can be many functions there? How does this work internally?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am guessing that variable routesApi contains a reference to the variable router of index.js

It contains a copy of the value of `module.exports` which was a copy of the value of `router`.

JavaScript doesn't support references to variables.

> What does require() return which is used in app.use()?

The same as it returns anywhere else. The express router object.

> How does app.use('/', routesApi) know which function to call from index.js. There can be many functions there?

It does URL path matching on the paths specified as the first argument to each of the routes created on the router.