# Accesing a function in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I building a discord bot and I want to decleare a function in another file to keep my documents cleaner.

I have 2 files:

function.js

```
const needle = require("needle");

async function get() {
  const res = await needle("get", endpointURL, params, {
        headers: {
            "User-Agent": "v2LikingUsersJS",
            authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
    });
     
    if (res.body) {
    return res.body;
    } else {
        throw new Error("Unsuccessful request");
    };
};
```

index.js

```
const imp = require("./function");

const data = await get();
```

If I run this code I get the error 'get is not a function'

I also tried:

```
"const data = await imp.get()";
```

Can anyone help me to get this running ?
Thank for your help in advance.

Comment: You have to export the function, then import/require it in the file you want to use it in. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this link might help you out as exporting and importing is what you want https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports

I'd suggest using something like the following in your main file

```js
import {yourFunction} from '/something.js';
```

and you can import multiple files and functions and then in your something.js if it was called that then you would add something like:

```js
export myFunction() {
//code
}
```